# Best practices to avoid pross-thread/process database accessment

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-patterns, linq-to-sql, multithreading

I am developing the MVC web application.

Which means I am creating views, models, view models. I use linq-to-sql as a database provider, I have implemented custom [Unit-of-Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern, and also the Data Source, Repositories and Service patterns which looks perfectly (in my implementation) and completely separated from the direct `SQL` code. Actually, from any database, which is designed for unit testing, so I could test my application with in-memory data sources with no affect on the database.

And eventually I am stuck with one problem: I have no protection agains cross thread (or cross process, because as far as I know, [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) can create more than one app domain with a single web app) operations.

For example, I have a table with some records. And every now and again a web request happens which (inside controller and then service and then repository) picks the SQL table' row on the maximum of let's say `TicketId` column and then inserts in that table another row with `(that column value + 1)`.

In the case two or more threads or processes do the same thing, the duplicated values can appear in the database. Some time ago, when my webapp was somekind smaller, I used the direct SQL code and simple `UPDLOCK` in [SELECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29) statements which inside [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) block was locking the record I'm modifying (or anything else) preventing all other database clients to wait until I finish.

With all these patterns I forgot one thing:
**How do I actually implement database multi-access protection issue**?
Without any direct SQL code.

Comment: Database identity should still be managed by the DB, let it do the +1. Its algorithms are already well tested :)

Comment: What algorithms? My repositories could run simultaneously producing duplicate values into the database and working in the same item twice. it will happen when two same web requests came in.

Comment: Not if you let the database generate the IDs.  That's why the IDENTITY feature of SQL Server exists.

Comment: I am not always need to do the +1. In other 50% cases I need to keep that `TicketId` value to the same maximum of all previous incrementing just `id` column (there is my identity you all was looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a single table to represent a ticket number and the use transaction with [Seriliazable transaction isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)?

```
int GetTicketNumber(bool shouldIncrement)
{

   if(shouldIncrement)
   {
     // use transaction with serilizable isolation level
     select and update
   }
   else
   {
     //just select
   }

}
```

Comment: Will `SELECT` clause (produced by `Linq-to-SQL` code, which is called by my repositories) place some kind of lock, in your example? So that other applications could not access that table until the transaction is committed or disposed?

Comment: Yes I think that will work; a transaction isolation level " SERIALIZABLE

Specifies the following:

Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions.

No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes.
" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: Thats a lock I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I actually implement database multi-access protection issue?

It's the database engine's job to do that. It's your job to ensure your app fails gracefully should there be any issues reported back. See [Locking in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190615%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

> For example, I have a table with some records. And every now and again a web request happens which 
>   (inside controller and then service and then repository) picks the SQL table' row on the maximum > of let's say TicketId column and then inserts in that table another row with (that column value + 1).

I get the impression here that you don't seem to have much faith in your database considering you are trying to replicate it's behaviour. Set your field to be `auto-increment` and that should solve your issue. If you do *have* to implement your own manual auto-increment then you need to use some form of locking because what you essentially have is a race condition e.g.

```
private static object lockObject = new Object();

lock(lockObject)
{
    ... DB stuff
}
```

For cross-process locking, you would need to look at possibly a named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: So how does it know when and where to place locks?

Comment: In some cases I need to use duplicate values. In some other cases I dont. That's why I need `+1` only **sometimes**.

Comment: [Locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx) will not prevent the code to be run within two or more appdomains simultaneously.

Comment: As far as I am aware, IIS **will not** create multiple AppDomains for a single site instance. Have you read something that says otherwise?

Comment: There may be multiply instances but in different processes. First of all, if Overlapped Recycle option of app pool is enabled (and it is enabled by default), there may be more than one w3wp process when recycling occures. Also there may be more than 1 instance if Maximum Worker Processes option is more than 1.

Comment: What if the application is load-balanced on two servers? then a lock on static object will not work

Comment: Yeah I imagine that's more along the lines of what AgentFire was getting at with the multiple AppDomains. @Ngm yep valid point, however, I don't think that is the underlying problem. You shouldn't be trying to re-implement database behaviour from your application (the locking scenario was just an example of how you would solve it generally). For cross-process locking the OP would need to look at a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @James agreed, was pointing out that a lock on static object does not guarantee that it will work in all scenarios.